# Level system in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Designing level system with features like number of days without warning,money earned in that duration,number of orders rating response rate...everything each level has its one requirements but how to design its database schema and relationships

```
public function level(){
 return $this->hasOne(Level::class);
}
```

database table:

Tables:

```
Level_table: 
 id,name

User_table:
id,level_id,user_rating
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two popular ways you can approach this. While you provide a number of metrics (orders, ratings, duration, earnings) let's simplify the example to 'points'.

The first scenario is a formulaic level system, where your concept of points constitutes a threshold and can be calculated on the fly. For example, >10 points is always 'silver'. If you have the ability to lose points in your system then you can duck below silver in this model.

The second is a more event-centric model, where changing over a threshold can change your level, but reverting doesn't reduce your level. This is much more like a 'season best' score for your points.

My initial thought is that the complexity in your code comes from the calculation of the level, not the storage (so its not necessarily in your model).

How you model this is *heavily* dependant on the things that depend on your levels or points. A few probing questions would be:

1. Does a level affect things like billing? What about access to services or features? Knowing this will influence how you hook into Laravel's authorisation code (validators, route access etc).
2. Does your level formulas fit into the first or second scenario (can people revert backwards a level). This helps you determine if you want to store the level or always calculate it (and maybe cache it...).
3. Does your level system decay? For your example with user warnings, do those warnings 'decay' over e.g. a month and are not factored in if they're too old? This helps you decide on any appropriate caching or filtering for input data to your scoring algorithm.

My initial instinct is to map a 'status' field to your primary entity or model. For example your User model might have a `level` field.  Transitions in your level field can then be handled by a state machine (do some further googling) that factors in all your calculations and scoring algorithms. Alternatively you could have it as a custom accessor on a model and calculate it on the fly.

Given my initial instinct, I'd simple have a field that is guarded:

```php
class User {
  //...
  protected $guarded = ['level'];
  // ...
}
```

A good example of a state transition between 'levels' (as an API) would be to look at Stripe's Billing/Invoices workflows.  While it's a very different business domain, it is however a simple API with a a *lot* of intricacies in the transitions between workflow statuses. You can look to those business rules as examples for inspiration of how you can structure your own code and data structures.

Last up, you probably want to hook into Laravel's event system to trigger 'levelling' events, and ensure that the transition between those levels is only handled by a single set of code (try to avoid calculating levels on the fly across a bunch of controllers - bring it all together in your service).

Oh and while you're thinking of schema... do you need to store someone's level history and reasons for 'transitioning' through the levels? Food for thought =D